# How to prevent your WiFi from getting hacked by Kali Linux?

Tags: wifi, attack-prevention, kali-linux

There is a tool on GitHub named HT-WPS Breaker by SilentGhostX (https://github.com/SilentGhostX/HT-WPS-Breaker) that can be used to break into others WiFi in seconds. How to prevent your WiFi from getting hacked ?

Comment: how about turning WPS off ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPS stands for [WiFi Protected Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Setup). It is a configuration protocol aimed to ease the configuration of (adding) new devices.

**WPS is not required** for WiFi network to work and the configuration that it automates can be performed manually.

As a non-essential protocol, the easiest and most reliable method of protecting against exploiting it, is **disabling the WPS altogether**.

---

The weakness in WPS mechanism is an ease of performing a brute-force attacks.

Implementations of WPS differ among devices and some vendors offer additional measures to impede the attack attempts, so it doesn't mean that a WPS-enabled device is inherently insecure.

The attacks on the other hand take advantage of insecure default settings or firmware bugs in some devices and there is no solution to the problem other than user awareness.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that some APs are immune to WPS attacks, using hardware techs to control timeouts after entering a wrong PIN by attacker.

Comment: @Emadeddin Yes, but I wonder if casual user is capable of assessing the implementation.

Comment: Yeah this process will work but some routers don't have the facility to disable WPS or even if they have it will totally make the router open (no authentication). So they can be the target of Reaver. Quite a disadvantage for them.